# blackfin gcc-toolchain linking error undefined reference to `Ret_Add'

Tags: gcc, linker, undefined, assembly, vdsp

Following discution:

https://blackfin.uclinux.org/gf/project/uclinux-dist/forum/?_forum_action=ForumMessageBrowse&thread_id=46813&action=ForumBrowse&forum_id=39

I'm converting the FFT algo for VDSP compiler to bare metal app to run on core B and have uclinux running on core A. I've a linking error I do not understand where it come from:

Invoking: '/opt/uClinux/bfin-elf/bin/../bfin-elf/bin/ld.real' '-v' '-o' 'test_ad1836_driver' '-T' 'coreb_test_ad1836_driver.lds' '--just-symbol' '../../icc_core/icc' 'queue.o' 'ezkit_561.o' 'heap_2.o' 'port.o' 'tasks.o' 'test_ad1836_driver.o' 'list.o' 'croutine.o' 'user_isr.o' 'bfin_isr.o' 'app_c.o' 'context_sl_asm.o' 'cycle_count.o' 'CFFT_Rad4_NS_NBRev.o' '-Ttext' '0x3c00000' '-L' '/opt/uClinux/bfin-elf/bfin-elf/lib' '-L' '/opt/uClinux/bfin-elf/bfin-elf/lib' '-lc'
GNU ld version 2.17
cycle_count.o: In function `Compute_Cycle_Count':
/home/william/Development_new/Music_Recognition/code/uCLinux/uclinux-dist/user/blkfin-apps/icc_utils/example/DSP_imp/CFFT_Rad4_NS_NBRev/corea/cycle_count.asm:22: undefined reference to`Ret_Add'
/home/william/Development_new/Music_Recognition/code/uCLinux/uclinux-dist/user/blkfin-apps/icc_utils/example/DSP_imp/CFFT_Rad4_NS_NBRev/corea/cycle_count.asm:23: undefined reference to `Ret_Add'
/home/william/Development_new/Music_Recognition/code/uCLinux/uclinux-dist/user/blkfin-apps/icc_utils/example/DSP_imp/CFFT_Rad4_NS_NBRev/corea/cycle_count.asm:27: undefined reference to`Save_R7'
/home/william/Development_new/Music_Recognition/code/uCLinux/uclinux-dist/user/blkfin-apps/icc_utils/example/DSP_imp/CFFT_Rad4_NS_NBRev/corea/cycle_count.asm:28: undefined reference to `Save_R7'
/home/william/Development_new/Music_Recognition/code/uCLinux/uclinux-dist/user/blkfin-apps/icc_utils/example/DSP_imp/CFFT_Rad4_NS_NBRev/corea/cycle_count.asm:44: undefined reference to`Save_R7'
/home/william/Development_new/Music_Recognition/code/uCLinux/uclinux-dist/user/blkfin-apps/icc_utils/example/DSP_imp/CFFT_Rad4_NS_NBRev/corea/cycle_count.asm:45: undefined reference to `Save_R7'
/home/william/Development_new/Music_Recognition/code/uCLinux/uclinux-dist/user/blkfin-apps/icc_utils/example/DSP_imp/CFFT_Rad4_NS_NBRev/corea/cycle_count.asm:48: undefined reference to`Ret_Add'
/home/william/Development_new/Music_Recognition/code/uCLinux/uclinux-dist/user/blkfin-apps/icc_utils/example/DSP_imp/CFFT_Rad4_NS_NBRev/corea/cycle_count.asm:49: undefined reference to `Ret_Add'

the code looks like:

.section l1.data;
.align 4;
    .var _Ret_Add =0;
        .var _Save_R7 =0;

.section l1.text;
.global _Compute_Cycle_Count;
.align 8;
_Compute_Cycle_Count:
        P0.L = _Ret_Add;
        P0.H = _Ret_Add;
        R3 = RETS;
        [P0] = R3;

```
    P0.L = _Save_R7;                                                       
    P0.H = _Save_R7;                                                       
    [P0] = R7;
```

........

Thanks

William

Comment: Er... do you really believe this question is presented so that it will inspire people to read it??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have no declaration of **_Ret_Add** and **_Save_R7** in your code to be understood by GNU assembler. You should port it from VDSP asm to GNU asm:

```
_Ret_Add: .int 0;
```

or maybe if you prefer keep it backwards compatible:

```
.if defined (__GNUC__)
_Ret_Add:
.int 0;
.else
.var _Ret_Add =0;
.endif
```

Take a look at [this](http://docs.blackfin.uclinux.org/doku.php?id=visualdsp%3aport_assembly_code&s%5B%5D=vdsp).

Comment: Great !!  It make sense. thanks pmod. The code compile now. for the question presentation I thought I was giving all the info:  context, compiler output and related code. I though it was clearer to understand this way. Let me know a better and more attractive way to ask this type of questions so I improve. Thanks Again

Comment: I'm glad that I could help. You could cleanup question to remove long pathnames which are not relevant